# Install Wordpress with custom directory layout without breakting media upload

Tags: installation, server

New security patches introduced to the Wordpress core on October, 14th break media upload on my Wordpress installations.

That's due to my uncommon directory structure:

- wp-config.php (custom)
- index.php (custom)
- wp (vanilla Wordpress Core)

  - wp-content (unused)
  - wp-cron.php
  - wp-blog-header.php
  - wp-includes
  - wp-admin
  - ...more...
- wp-content (my custom, used wp-content directory)

  - plugins
  - themes
- uploads (my custom, used uploads-directory)

So I set WP_SITEURL to my "wp"-directory, WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL to my "wp-content"-directory and WP_PLUGIN_DIR and WP_PLUGIN_URL to my "wp-content/plugins"-directory.

Because Wordpress contructs the path of the uploads-Directory relative to the Wordpress core I needed to set UPLOADS to '../uploads'. So the resulting path of upload_dir() is "/wp/../uploads/" - that worked so far.

In October, 14th with 5.2.4 there was a change to how wp_mkdir_p() (in wp-includes/functions.php) sanitizes and checks the path of new directories it creates. Here's the SVN log:

---

r46274 | whyisjake | 2019-10-14 15:31:04 +0000 (Mo, 14. Okt 2019) | 8 Zeilen

Filesystem API: Prevent directory travelersals when creating new folders.

Reject file paths that contain sub-directory paths.

Props iandunn, xknown, sstoqnov, whyisjake.

Built from https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk@46476

---

There's a newly added block of code that goes like this:

```
// Do not allow path traversals.
if ( false !== strpos( $target, '../' ) || false !== strpos( $target, '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ) ) {
    return false;
}
```

So all my Wordpress installations are unable to create a new directory "2019/11" in their uploads directory. However, if i manually create the folder, upload works, it's just the creation of new subfolders that stopped working.

My question: What's the best way to configure Wordpress in a way that allows me to keep my filesystem structure. One possibility is to modify the apply_filters( 'upload_dir',  $uploads ) to remove the unnecessary "wp/../" from the path, but that requires a plugin and i'd like to get Wordpress working on my servers without having to install a plugin in each (because there are much of them).

Comment: Wordpress Bug: [https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48506]
Other guys with the same problem: [https://foliovision.com/2019/11/wordpress-unable-to-create-directory]

Comment: Hi @Matthias.... in your specific situation, is it necessary to keep your uploads sorted by year/month (as is default)?  In mine, I don't particularly want all those additional folders created so I "uncheck" the box under Settings>Media that says "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders"...... if you don't need the extra folders, once you're setup then there is no need to continually be creating new folders within your structure....just a thought....